# Get name of the class where the given spark session object was created

Tags: apache-spark, listener

I have a query listener where I would fetch data from the QueryListener object and send it to an API.

```java
public class QueryListener implements QueryExecutionListener {

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(String funcName, QueryExecution qe, long durationNs) {

        SparkSession sparkSession = qe.sparkSession();

        //then fetch data from QueryExecution object

    }
}
```

I want to have an identifier so that I can track which module/class the data belongs to. Say class X creates the spark session, and the listener gets called for it, I want a way to tell (inside the listener) that X was the class for which this listener was called and all the data inside the QueryExecution object belongs to that class.

I am not able to find this particular info from the spark session object. I tried checking methods like conf() but it doesn't have the info. Does anyone knows how to do it using the spark session object?

Also, I can't go with identifier like appName (`sparkSession.sparkContext().appName()`) because I don't have access to change the calling methods and I see that most of them don't have this parameter set. Hence, I would be getting some default value when using this. That's why I opted to go with class name for it.

Please let me know any solutions for this or any other alternatives which might work.